# How to check the validation of edit text for pan card in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, validation

I have to validate the test is a valid pan card with help of some regular expression in iOS app development .can any one help this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PAN is a 10 digit alpha numeric number, where the first 5 characters are letters, the next 4 numbers and the last one a letter again. These 10 
characters can be divided in five parts as can be seen below. The meaning of each number has been explained further.

1. First three characters are alphabetic series running from AAA to ZZZ
2. Fourth character of PAN represents the status of the PAN holder.

   • C — Company

   • P — Person

   • H — HUF(Hindu Undivided Family)

   • F — Firm

   • A — Association of Persons (AOP)

   • T — AOP (Trust)

   • B — Body of Individuals (BOI)

   • L — Local Authority

   • J — Artificial Juridical Person

   • G — Government
3. Fifth character represents first character of the PAN holder’s last name/surname.
4. Next four characters are sequential number running from 0001 to 9999.
5. Last character in the PAN is an alphabetic check digit

Here my code.

```
 - (BOOL)validatePancard:(NSString *)candidate 
{
    NSString *panCardRegex = @"[A-Z]{3}P[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", panCardRegex]; return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Comment: Would be good to add in a sentence or two explaining why this is a good solution.

Comment: @remus, i have added more detail,please look that.

Comment: Nearly there - use the code formatting markdown syntax on your code snippets though ;)

Answer (score 6):

PAN card validation for swift 4.0

```
 func validatePANCardNumber(_ strPANNumber : String) -> Bool{
        let regularExpression = "[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}"
        let panCardValidation = NSPredicate(format : "SELF MATCHES %@", regularExpression)
        return panCardValidation.evaluate(with: strPANNumber)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is very simple function to validate Pan card number.

```
- (BOOL) validatePanCardNumber: (NSString *) cardNumber {
    NSString *emailRegex = @"^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$";
    NSPredicate *cardTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [cardTest evaluateWithObject:cardNumber];
}
```

For Calling this method.

```
 NSLog(@"%hhd",[self validatePanCardNumber:@"XXXX1111X"]);
```

With using this your problem solve.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code:

```
- (BOOL)check:(NSString *)input
{
   NSString *pattern = @"^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]$"

   NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NULL error:&error];
   NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:input options:NSMatchingProgress range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length)];

   return matches.length && matches[0].range.location == 0       
}
```